# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present when resource from Origin is 10 files or more, but fine when 9 or less

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

Configure Services method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
            corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SiteCorsPolicy", corsBuilder.Build());
            });
         }
```

Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("SiteCorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Post

```
[EnableCors("SiteCorsPolicy")]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("import")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
        {}
```

Angular code

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    var data = new FormData();

    for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
      data.append('files', files.item(x));
    }

    this.http.post("https://localhost:44334/api/files/import", data).subscribe();
  }
```

Like the title says, when I select 9 files or less, the post and code work fine. However, when I try to select 10 files or more, I get the following error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44334/api/files/import' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST https://localhost:44334/api/files/import net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Hi @BrandonButterworth, any updates about this case? If the answer resolved the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I select 9 files or less, the post and code work fine. However, when I try to select 10 files or more, I get the following error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44334/api/files/import' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If the request exceed the `maxAllowedContentLength` limitation, which would cause the issue.

To fix it, you can try to modify and increase the value of `maxAllowedContentLength` base d on your actual scenario, like below.

```
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="90000000" />
</requestFiltering>
```

For testing purpose on local IIS express, you can try to add above code in corresponding .config file (PROJECT_FOLDER\PROJECT_NAME.vs\PROJECT_NAME\config\applicationhost.config).

```
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="90000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```